# Haskell: Parse error in pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, operator-precedence, parse-error

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with this code (syntactically)?

```
-- merge two sorted lists
mergeX [] b res = b ++ res
mergeX a [] res = a ++ res
mergeX a:as b:bs res
    | a > b     = mergeX as b:bs a:res
    | otherwise = mergeX a:as bs b:res
```

Interpreter:

> Parse error in pattern: mergeX

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need some parenthesis:

```
mergeX [] b res = b ++ res
mergeX a [] res = a ++ res
mergeX (a:as) (b:bs) res
    | a > b     = mergeX as (b:bs) (a:res)
    | otherwise = mergeX (a:as) bs (b:res)
```

The reason is because `:` has a lower precedence than function application, so `mergeX a:as b:bs res` will be parsed as:

```
(mergeX a):(as b):(bs res)
```

which is an error.

Comment: Thanks, I remember that I had sth. like that before ;).
Do you normally always use (x:xs) instead of x:xs to prevent mistakes?

Comment: @user905686: In a pattern, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put constructor patterns (or however they are called) in parantheses.

```
mergeX (a:as) (b:bs) res
```