# Parse error in pattern Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, operator-precedence, parse-error

Why am I getting a parse error in this code?

```
data One = H| I deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
data E = A | B deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
type L = [E]

fun1 :: One -> E -> One
-- function for fun1 is here

fun2 :: One -> L -> One
fun2 a [] = a
fun2 a x:xs = fun2 (fun1 a x) xs    --<<< I am getting error here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
fun2 a (x:xs) = fun2 (fun1 a x) xs
```