# Haskell : "Parse error in pattern:" when creating a maximum' function

Tags: haskell, max

So I am trying to implement a maximum function but for some reason I am getting a parse error on the last line "mymax x:y:ys = ..... " . What is the reason for that error? Thanks!

```
mymax :: Ord a=>[a]->Maybe a
mymax [] = Nothing
mymax [x] = Just x
mymax x:y:xs = if (x < y) 
            then mymax(y:xs) 
            else mymax(x:xs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses:

```
mymax (x:y:xs) = if (x < y) 
                 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Put parenthesis around `x:y:xs`

```
mymax (x:y:xs) = ...
```