# Haskell syntax error in my function

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

I have tried to write a function that takes a list pair, and swaps the
pair elements

```
inverse :: [(a,b)] -> [(b,a)]
inverse [] = []
inverse (x,y):xs = (y:x): inverse xs
```

I have loaded this function via Prelude, it gives me following error:

> mydefs.hs:11:1: Parse error in pattern: inverse

This is line 11, `inverse (x,y):xs = (y:x): inverse xs`

Comment: colon in `(y:x)` to `(y,x)`...

Comment: A better way of doing this would be making a function `swap (a,b) = (b,a)` and making `inverse = map swap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to surround the unpacked tuple and the rest of the list, like this

```
inverse ((x, y):xs) = (y, x) : inverse xs
```

Apart from this, you can use the [`Data.Tuple` package's `swap` function](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap), like this

```
Prelude> import Data.Tuple
Prelude Data.Tuple> map swap [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(2,1),(4,3)]
```