# Why are parentheses needed with `:` in this context?

Tags: haskell

Typing the following into a GHC interpreter yields no error:

```
let head' (x:_) = x
```

But if we remove the parentheses:

```
let head' x:_ = x
```

...we obtain:

> Parse error in pattern: head'

Why are the parentheses necessary?

Comment: because the other patter would be equal to `(head' x) : _` (remember application has the highest precedence) and this would only make sense for an Data-Constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Haskell, function application has higher precedence than any operator, and pattern-matching reflects that.

So, without the parentheses, `head' x:_` is parsed as `(head' x):_`, which doesn't make sense in this context, and causes an error.