# Haskell says parse error

Tags: haskell

```
smallestNumberH (x:xs) n = if(xs==[])then n else (if(x<n) then smallestNumberH xs x else smallestNumberH xs n)
smallestNumber (x:xs) = smallestNumberH (x:xs) x
countmin::[Int]->Int
countmin l:ls = if (ls==[]) then 0 else (if(l==smallestNumber ls) then (1 + countmin ls) else (countmin ls))
```

It says "Parse error in pattern: countmin". I tried to add l: next to ls but it doesn't work.

Comment: You also have some non-exhaustive patters. Try compiling with `-Wall` to see those before they cause runtime errors.

Comment: If you want your helper function to only handle the case where there's at least one element, make that element a separate argument to the helper function so it's clear that it will always be there. Your main function should certainly handle the empty case somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parentheses around your pattern matching for countmin. Change it to:

```
countmin (l:ls) = ...
```

Comment: It works here: http://rextester.com/KHHM55458. All that was changed is the parentheses around `(l:ls)`

Comment: Well it won't work on empty lists if that's the only change you make.