# error in patternmatching in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

I am writing a function that maps lists of lists of bools invectively into lists of bools. This is my code:

```
y=[False| y<-[0..]]    
encode :: [[Bool]] -> [Bool]
encode x:xs =   (zip1 x y):True:True:(encode xs)
encode []=[]
```

The zip1 function just takes two lists and writes them alternating into a new list.

I'm getting the error message

> Parse error in pattern: encode

Why do I get this error message?

Comment: it's probably just `encode (x:xs)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function application has higher precedence than `:`

Thus, Haskell parses

```
encode x:xs
```

as

```
(encode x):xs
```

which makes no sense. You need

```
encode (x:xs)
```