# Haskell - list operation: Parse error in pattern

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation, addition

I am writing in `Haskell` a function that gets two lists of type `Int` and adds the values of one list to that one of the other.

for example: `addElements [1,2,3] [4,5,6]` will give the output: `[5,7,9]`

my function so far:

```
addElements :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addElements [] [] = []
addElements x:xs [] = x:xs
addElements [] y:ys = y:ys
addElements x:xs y:ys = [x+y] ++ addElements xs ys
```

I keep getting the error:

> Parse error in pattern: addElements Failed, modules loaded: none

I do not get any additional information - what have I done wrong?

Comment: I think you need parenthesis around the `x:xs` and `y:ys` pattern matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need parentheses around your patterns. It should be `(x:xs)`, not `x:xs` on its own. That's what is causing the compiler confusion.

```hs
addElements :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addElements [] [] = []
addElements (x:xs) [] = x:xs
addElements [] (y:ys) = y:ys
addElements (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x+y] ++ addElements xs ys
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the OP, but I just wanted to point out that the patterns can be simplified to:

```
addElements :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addElements xs [] = xs
addElements [] ys = ys
addElements (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : addElements xs ys
```