# Haskell - finding smallest Element in list

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, parse-error

I have a function that gets a List and has to return the smallest Element of it.

Unfortunately I keep getting the issue:

> Parse error in pattern: minim

What could I have done wrong?

```
minim :: [Int] -> Int
minim []       = 0
minim [x]      = x
minim x:xs     = min x (minim xs)

min :: Int -> Int -> Int
min a b
    | a > b  = b
    | a < b  = a
```

Comment: You are missing a case in min also, where a and b are equal

Comment: I have added   | a == b = 0. Now I get the issue: Ambigous ocurrence 'main'. I have saved and recompiled the file before.

Comment: What about this one-liner? `foldl (\x y->if x<y then x else y) (maxBound::Int) [2,5,2,3,5]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Parse error in pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561762/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to solve it the most Haskell way. I would solve it as such:

```
-- Does not work for empty lists (so maybe needs to be wrapped in some logic)
foldr1 min [-3,1,2,3]
-- Works for empty but needs a "default value" (in this case 0)
foldr min 0 [-3,1,2,3]
```

If you want to learn by implementing it yourself, then this works for me

```
minim :: [Int] -> Int
minim []       = 0
minim [x]      = x
minim (x:xs)   = min x (minim xs)

min :: Int -> Int -> Int
min a b
    | a > b  = b
    | a < b  = a
    | a == b = a
```

I would however make it a bit more safe, because is really 0 the smallest int in the list if it is empty? I think you should use `Nothing` as the result.

```
import Data.Maybe

import Prelude hiding (min)

main = print $  minim [1,3,4, 6,6,-9]

minim :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
minim []       = Nothing
minim [x]      = Just x
minim (x:xs)   = min x <$> minim xs

min :: Int -> Int -> Int
min a b
    | a > b  = b
    | a < b  = a
    | a == b = a
```

Comment: `0` is a pretty bad initialiser for `min`, don't you think? Maybe `minim [] = 1/0` ?

Comment: The third equation for `minim` is pretty awkward, with the `fromJust` call and another mention of `Just` as well. Better would be: `minim (x:xs) = min x <$> minim xs`.

Comment: @amalloy, thanks for the suggestion, felt that something was strange with having "Just" there, but didn't get it to work. Not very familiar with <$> (or Functors/monads at all) but now i learned something, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [minimum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:minimum).

```
> minimum [2, 1, 3]
> 1
```

Comment: Don't use `minimum` from Prelude, it's a partial function. Use `Data.Foldable1.minimum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have one parameter that you want to match (the list of `Int`s).  Where you want to match parts of that list you need to put these in brackets to show the compiler you are matching one thing.   Thus the last pattern should be `(x:xs)`.

Comment: Your explanation seems correct and logic to me. Unfortunately for 'minim x:[]     = x' I still get error in parse pattern.

Comment: @jublikon: my bad I've noticed a second problem!

Comment: `[x]` is a perfectly fine (a much clearer) way to match a list of one.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: ah, I hadn't realised that, I've always used the cons operator (so when told that there was a syntax error but not which line that looked wrong to me).

Comment: @dave Many would love to see that misinformation is removed from SO answers. Therefore, I kindly ask you to edit yours accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here's another way of implementing what you asked but without having to use auxiliary functions such as min

```
minElem::[Int]->Int
minElem [] = 0
minElem [x] = x
minElem (x:y:xs) 
 |x > y = minElem (y:xs)
 |x < y = minElem (x:xs)
 |x == y = minElem (x:xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should not take lists, because it makes no sense to conjure up a minimum of e.g. 0 for empty lists, when the element type may even be allowing negative values. To have total safety and generality, we can use the [Min type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Min). First, let's make an example input value:

```
exampleList = 1 :| [2, 3, 4]
```

The `:|` is the constructor for non-empty lists, which are more suited.

To find the minimum, we can use the `sconcat`, which combines all elements of a non-empty list using the Semigroup operation, which will in this case be like the `min` function on two elements shown in other answers.

```
> sconcat $ fmap Min exampleList
Min {getMin = 1}
```

To extract the number from the `Min`, you can use `getMin`.

Answer (score 0):

In GHC 9.6, Data.Foldable1 with the class Foldable1 was added. Foldable1 is for all structures that are non-empty.

The class has a method called [minimum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable1.html#v:minimum).

If you use an old version of GHC, you can use the compatibility package [foldable1-classes-compat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldable1-classes-compat).